# JavaScript merge array objects with the same keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with several objects some have the same keys (Question and  QuestionId), for example:

```
    var jsonData = [
            {
                Question: "Was the training useful?",
                QuestionId: 1,
                myData: [{ name: 'No', value: 1 }] },
            {
                Question: "Was the training useful?",
                QuestionId: 1 ,
                myData: [{ name: 'Yes', value: 1 }]
        }];
```

How can I combine these objects into one, expected output:

```
      var jsonData = [
        {
            Question: "Was the training useful?",
            QuestionId: 1,
            myData: [{ name: 'No', value: 1 },
                     { name: 'Yes', value: 1 }] 
          }];
```

Comment: could initialize a new array, and loop through all your data, looking to see if there's already an instance of your two key value pairs, and if so, add the `myData` value to the entry in your new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var jsonData = [{
    Question: "Was the training useful?",
    QuestionId: 1,
    myData: [{
      name: 'No',
      value: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    Question: "Was the training useful?",
    QuestionId: 1,
    myData: [{
      name: 'Yes',
      value: 1
    }]
  }
];

const result = Object.values(jsonData.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (!acc[obj.QuestionId]) {
    acc[obj.QuestionId] = obj;
  } else {
    acc[obj.QuestionId].myData = acc[obj.QuestionId].myData ?? []; // if myData is null or undefined, set it to an empty array
    acc[obj.QuestionId].myData = acc[obj.QuestionId].myData.concat(obj.myData);
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That is great thank you.  However, it returned two objects, the first is the merged myData, and the second object with the Yes answer, I was hoping to return only one object.

Comment: @hncl see the snippet, it's working as you expected

Comment: @hncl not sure what you mean, can you share the output?

Comment: @HellaMad, it is working now as expected.  I have accepted your answer, thanks

Comment: @pilchard, thank you; my challenge is the array is generated using Ajax.  I get this error: acc[obj.QuestionId].myData.concat is not a function.  I tried to run the script as a function on Ajax complete, still get the same error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @hncl 
I'm assuming myData might be null or undefined. If that's the case, see the updated answer.

Comment: @HellaMad, thank you.  I still get this error: acc[obj.QuestionId].myData.concat is not a function.  I have posted another question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850916/javascript-merge-ajax-array-objects-with-the-same-keys?noredirect=1#comment126969361_71850916

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mergeData(data) {
  const acc = {}
  data.forEach(x => {
    const id = x.QuestionId
    if (!acc[id]) acc[id] = x
    else acc[id].myData = acc[id].myData.concat(x.myData)
  })
  return Object.values(acc)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach to create an object where the keys are the question IDs and then use Object.values to get the values into an array.

```js
var jsonData = [{
  Question: "Was the training useful?",
  QuestionId: 1,
  myData: [{ name: 'No', value: 1 }] 
}, {
  Question: "Was the training useful?",
  QuestionId: 1 ,
  myData: [{ name: 'Yes', value: 1 }]
}];

var temp = {};
jsonData.forEach(x=>{
  if(!temp[x.QuestionId]) {temp[x.QuestionId] = x;} 
  else {temp[x.QuestionId].myData.push(x.myData);}
});

var arr = Object.values(temp);

console.log(arr);
```